# android - MYSQL PHP Android Chat not work

Tags: android, listview

Momently I'm working on an android chat application for my Website. At my Website I can chat in realtime but in my android app I don't know how to update the Listview when I got a new message. Also I would like get an notifycation at the device when the app don't open and I get a new message.

A least I have an app with an Chat overview. Also I can pen the chat, read old messages and send a new one. But after sending a new message the listview hasn't been updated.

Here are some Steps how I send/recive the messages:

**SENDING MESSAGES**:

```
void send_message(final String message) {
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        private String result = "";
        public void run() {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            try{
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mywebsite.com/app/send_message.php?email="+ MainActivity.user_email+"&with="+ chat_with+"&message="+message);
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                showAlert("ERROR", "No connection to Internet.");
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
    getData(chat_with);
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_chat);
    while(!this.dataComplete) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    this.updateData();

}
```

1. Get new message content from editText
2. POST the data to an PHP file on my webserver
3. The PHP script insert the messsage and change the chat status for new mesages from a friend to 1
4. Update the Listview(not working yet)

**RECIVE MESSAGES**:

```
public void get_messages(final String with_user) {
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        private String result = "";
        public void run() {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            try{
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mywebsite.com/app/get_messages.php?email="+ MainActivity.user_email+"&with="+ with_user);
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                showAlert("ERROR", "No connection to Internet.");
            }
            try{
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "n");
                }
                is.close();
                result=sb.toString();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                showAlert("ERROR","Can't parse data.");
            }
            try{
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    results_messages.add((String) json_data.get("message"));
                }
                dataComplete = true;
            }
            catch(JSONException e){
                showAlert("ERROR","No connection to Internet.");
            }
        }};
    t.start();
}
```

1. Get logged in user infos and friend infos
2. POST data to PHP file on my webserver
3. Get messages as json response
4. Convert json to listview
5. Auto refresh Listview if I get a new message(not working yet)

**And to fill the Listview I use:**

```
public void fillList() {
    listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results_messages));
}
```

I hope I get some helpful answers.
Tip: `message_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` I test but it don't work

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the relevant source code? That would be much better than describing what your code does.

Comment: I hope this code is enough